# "Close Others" command shortcut in Sublime Text 2

Tags: command, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to add a shortcut for "Close Others" tabs, but can't seem to find the command, here is what I am trying:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+w"], "command": "close_others" }
```

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - sort of like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in OS X, close all *except* the current tab, see?

Anyway, `close_others` doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried `close_other_windows`, `close_other_tabs`, nothing works. What is the right command to do that?

And while we're on it, how do you know what commands are available? My next one will be <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - "Close Tabs to the Right".

For some improvements in Sublime window management see "[Close all tabs, but not the window, in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561487/solved-sublime-text-2-close-all-tabs-but-not-the-window-how)"

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The command is `close_others_by_index`. Unfortunately, it takes arguments that cannot be passed via a simple key binding.

To make it work, you have to create a plugin. `Tools/New Plugin...`:

```py
import sublime_plugin

class CloseOthersCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        window = self.view.window()
        group_index, view_index = window.get_view_index(self.view)
        window.run_command("close_others_by_index", { "group": group_index, "index": view_index})
```

Save it in `Packages/User` directory. Then you can add your key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+w"], "command": "close_others" }
```

The same is true for "Close tabs to the right". The command is `close_to_right_by_index`.

The plugin:

```py
import sublime_plugin

class CloseToRightCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        window = self.view.window()
        group_index, view_index = window.get_view_index(self.view)
        window.run_command("close_to_right_by_index", { "group": group_index, "index": view_index})
```

The key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+shift+w"], "command": "close_to_right" }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! How do you know all this stuff? Hope this will be improved in Sublime 3.

Comment: I searched for `close_others` string on all files under `Packages` directory. The only result was `close_others_by_index` used in `Default/Tab Context.sublime-menu`. `get_view_index` is explained in [Sublime Text  documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Window).

Comment: When I created a new plugin with that code, it didn't work. To fix it, I added a newline at the end of the plugin file, and I needed two empty lines between the import and class definition. This is my first time ever writing Python and a Sublime plugin; were these Python-issues or Sublime-issues?

Comment: Those blank lines are suggested by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) style guide, but they shouldn't be mandatory. Anyway, it is a Python-issue.

Comment: It is really handy plugins, you should put this on github or somewhere  where people can pull from. Thank you for good job!

Comment: Working perfect on Sublime 3. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to clear **all** your tabs, you can add `{ "keys": ["super+shift+alt+w"], "command": "close_all" }` to your key bindings in Sublime 3.

Answer (score 10):

i made a sublime-plugin for that
(and for the "Close Other Windows" Functionality)

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CloseOtherWindows

Comment: Ace! Just what I needed :)

Comment: Awesome! More than just a solution.

Comment: Thx Manfred! This is very useful