# "Close tabs in current pane" command for Sublime Text 2

Tags: command, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Like many others, I use panels extensively in Sublime Text 2 (View->Layout->etc).

I'd like to map a shortcut to close all tabs in the **active** panel.
I know the `close_all`and `close_others` commands exist as documented in the following SO questions:

- [Close all tabs, but not the window, in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561487/close-all-tabs-but-not-the-window-in-sublime-text-2)
- ["Close Others" command shortcut in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379860/close-others-command-shortcut-in-sublime-text-2)

However, I haven't been able to find a command to close just the tabs in the active pane.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a file in your `Packages/User` directory named `closetabsinpane.py` with these contents:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class CloseViewsInGroupCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        for v in self.window.views_in_group(self.window.active_group()):
            g, view_index = self.window.get_view_index(v)
            self.window.run_command("close_by_index", { "group": g, "index": view_index})
```

And add a shortcut to your user keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+x"], "command": "close_views_in_group" },
```